# [ACCESS VBA]How to append tables with loop?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to append multiple tabkes into one table which all tables have same fields.

I have tried below codes:

```
Sub tr1()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim strSQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb


db.Execute "Delete * From Grouping"

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
If (tdf.Name Like "ab*" Or tdf.Name Like "cd*") Then
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Grouping " & " SELECT * FROM" & tdf.Name & ";"
db.Execute strSQL

End If
Next
End Sub
```

However, I have got error with these codes and I have no idea on how to fix it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `"INSERT INTO Grouping " & " SELECT * FROM" & tdf.Name & ";"`
there's no space between FROM and the table name. First step to debug the SQL should be to `debug.print` the sql string.

Answer (score 0):

With your code:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Grouping " & " SELECT * FROM" & tdf.Name & ";"
```

there's no space between `FROM` and the table name.
It should be:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Grouping " & " SELECT * FROM " & tdf.Name & ";"
```

Please do some basic debugging next time!